# PouchDB doesn't sync on some devices

Tags: ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb

I am developing a WPA in Ionic, and it uses PouchDB/CouchDB Synchronization.

When running in my PC the sync works and I can compare my login and password with the one stored in the DB, and I can access the website.
When accessing the website through my Huawei P9, it works too.
But through my Samsung S5, the synchronization simply doesn't even start.

I just realized that in my Samsung S5, as soon as sync starts (or should start) the "pause" event is fired and then nothing ever happens.

A friend of mine can't access from his PC, but he can access from his smartphone.

I don't understand what could be the problem

UPDATE: Another friend of mine could access through his smartphone, but now, after a software update, it can't. As the previous cases, sync does not even start

UPDATE2: Solved! It seems that the problem was the short internal memory in the phone. I moved a lot oh photos from the internal memory to the SD card and now it works

Comment: Did you check the storage before ? Just a write/read on a local database, may be the issue

Comment: @Noelmout if you mean the available storage on my smartphone, I have more than 700 MB free, I don't think that's the issue